# Hover effect in navigation menu (wordpress)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I´m creating web page in wordpress, and I have navigation menu using
`<?php wp_nav_menu(); ?>` .. The problem is, I want to create hover effect, displayed in enclosed image. 
http://s11.postimage.org/gclhor5hv/try.jpg

The problem is, I don´t know how to create that triangle on the bottom of the hovered list item. 
Here´s the CSS:
`#navHead li a:hover{

 background-color: #e00d1d;

 border-radius: 5px;

 color: #fff!important;

 background-repeat: no-repeat;

 background-position: 50% 30px;

}`

In HTML: navigation list is generated, so I can´t reach and edit structure, so it has to be done in CSS.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This generator will generate the css for a speech bubble in CSS 3: http://cssarrowplease.com/

Comment: For this he's probably better off using a background image that shows on hover.  CSS3 is great, as long as you're not concerned with IE.  Some of the newest CSS3 stuff still doesn't work in IE.  And forget about IE8 or less and CSS3.